# Failed to Load View State

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I encountered this problem [image]and I'm not familiar with this error.. Please see image. Please advice

Comment: Most likely the answer to your "question" is contained in the error message itself. Are you adding controls dynamically?

Comment: Failed to view load view state image... most of the text in that image is too small to read

Comment: @imuseless, it would help a lot if you could share the code that is responsible for adding controls.